# Solve the differential equation $\{xy\log \frac{x}{y}\}dx+\{y^2-x^2 \log \frac{x}{y}\}dy=0$ given that $y(1)=0$.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, homogeneous-equation

Solve the differential equation $\{xy\log \frac{x}{y}\}dx+\{y^2-x^2 \log \frac{x}{y}\}dy=0$ given that $y(1)=0$.

I was able to find the solution to it by the method of solving homogeneous differential equations, which is as follows:

$\frac {x^2}{2y^2} \log \frac{x}{y}-\frac {x^2}{4y^2}+ \log y = C$.

But I am not able to find the value of $C$, I am not getting how to substitute for $y$ because it seems to give not-defined values. Please help.

According to the answer hint, $C=1- \frac{3}{4e^2}$.

Thanks in advance...

**EDIT:**

Since most of you are asking for the complete steps I followed to get the final solution, I am posting it as follows:

$\{xy\log \frac{x}{y}\}dx+\{y^2-x^2 \log \frac{x}{y}\}dy=0$

Let $x=vy \implies \frac{dx}{dy}=v+y \frac{dv}{dy}$

Therefore, $\frac{dx}{dy}=-(\frac{y^2-x^2 \log \frac{x}{y}}{xy\log \frac{x}{y}})$

$\implies v+y \frac{dv}{dy}= \frac{v^2 \log v-1}{v \log v}$

$\implies y \frac{dv}{dy}= \frac{v^2 \log v-1}{v \log v}-v=\frac{-1}{v \log v}$

$\implies v \log v dv + \frac{1}{y} dy = 0$

Integrating the equation we get,

$\frac{v^2}{2} \log v-\frac{v^2}{4}+\log y=C$

On replacing value of $v=\frac{x}{y}$

$\frac {x^2}{2y^2} \log \frac{x}{y}-\frac {x^2}{4y^2}+ \log y = C$

Now, $y(1)=0$

Therefore, $\frac {1^2}{2\times 0^2} \log \frac{1}{0}-\frac {1^2}{4\times 0^2}+ \log 0 = C$

How do I solve for $C$? Please help...

Comment: Maybe better show your work ! are you sure about your final answer ?

Comment: I'm not sure there exist solutions to this differential equation satisfying $y\leq 0$ at any point.

Comment: @Khosrotash I am sure about the final answer. I solved it by assuming $\frac{x}{y}=v$, then solving the way we solve for homogeneous differential equations. But I am stuck at $C$...

Comment: @Khosrotash Please have a look at the complete solution, I edited the question...

Comment: I think ,put $y=\epsilon  $ and then find c with respect to $(1,\epsilon) $ .So you can do this after $\epsilon  \to 0$

Answer (score 1):

$$\left(xy\log\frac{x}{y}\right)dx+\left(y^2-x^2\log\frac{x}{y}\right)=0$$
$$\left(xy\log\frac{y}{x}\right)dx=\left(y^2+x^2\log\frac{y}{x}\right)dy$$ $$\left(\frac{y}{x}\log\frac{y}{x}\right)dx=\left(\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)^2+\log\frac{y}{x}\right)dy$$ Let $\frac{y}{x}=u \implies y=ux \implies \frac{dy}{dx}=u+x\frac{du}{dx}$

$$\left(u\log u\right)=\left(u^2+\log u\right)\left(u+x\frac{du}{dx}\right)$$ 
$$x\frac{du}{dx}=\frac{u\log u}{u^2+\log u}-u$$ 
$$x\frac{du}{dx}=\frac{u\log u-u^3-u\log u}{u^2+\log u}=\frac{-u^3}{u^2+\log u}$$
$$\frac{(u^2+\log u)du}{u^3}=-\frac{dx}{x}$$

Can you take it from here?

Comment: He was able to solve this , but he can't find "c" !

Comment: I have found the solution already... I assumed $\frac{x}{y}=u$ instead of $\frac{y}{x}$, as you did.... but the solution is coming out to be the same...... But I am stuck in the final stage, where I have to find the value of $C$ from $y(1)=0$.... Any idea on how to approach?

Comment: you can easily find out the value of constant $c$ by substituting $x=1$ & $y=0$ in the final solution & solving for $c$.

Comment: but $\log 0$ is not defined and $y^2$ is in the denominator.... I am putting all my steps to the answer shortly...

Comment: Please have a look at the complete steps, I just edited the question...